# Erros accessing nested value in API JSON response ... the question no one has solved yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, material-ui

I am populating an edit form using an API call which is returning values in this format:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "location1",
    "description": "Heating Plate",
    "isArchived": 0,
    "departmentOther": {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Tools",
        "description": "Tools Department",
        "isArchived": 0,
        "version": 1,
    }
}
```

Here is my API call:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${editUrl + (selectedRecord.id)}`);
    setValues( res.data );
  };
  fetchData();
}, [setValues]);
```

I am having troubles calling to the values inside of `departmentOther` data element.

In my edit page I tried calling to the Id to match a value in the dropdown list like so:

```
   const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

     <Dropdown
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            label='Department'
            name='departmentName'
            value={values.departmentOther.id}
            prompt='Select A Department...'
      />
```

**the dropdown component**

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const { error = null, label, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

  return(
    <FormControl >
        <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
        <Select
                defaultValue=''
                onChange={onChange}
                value={(value === undefined || value === null || options.length === 0) ? '' : value} 
                {...other}
                {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
            >
            <MenuItem>{prompt}</MenuItem>
            {options.map((option, id) => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option.id}
                    value={option.id}
                >
                    {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>

    );
}
```

But I end up getting a console error that reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

The console error causes the form to fail and not load, meaning my values are empty.
How do you call to a value in this kind of formatting?

I have also tried all of these ways of calling the value:

```
    value={values.departmentOther?.id}
    value={values.departmentOther[0].id}
    value={values['departmentOther']['id']}
    value={values['departmentOther'][0]['id']}
```

The only one that did not give me a similar console error was `value={values.departmentOther?.id}` but when I select an option from the dropdown, rather than it updating the `departmentOther` Id, it places the value into a new data element called undefined. Like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "location1",
    "description": "Heating Plate",
    "isArchived": 0,
    "departmentOther": {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Tools",
        "description": "Tools Department",
        "isArchived": 0,
        "version": 1,
    },
    "undefined": 22
}
```

If I use the same dropdown to update a data element that is not nested, it works just fine, so I know the dropdown is functioning properly, it is just a matter of accessing values inside the `departmentOther` object. The values variable above is also used to house all values for the form, which has multiple text fields. Everything not using a nest value work exactly as expected with no errors.

Can someone please show me how can I access this value so I am able to update it?  Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You're passing `values.departmentOther.id` to Dropdown, but it looks like `values` is an array that contains elements that have a departmentOther in them. Don't you want to pass all of `values` to the dropdown so you can map over them in the `Select`? You've also got `options` in your dropdown (in the map) but it's not clear where they're supposed to come from initially.

Comment: @ZacAnger, no the dropdown contains a list of all available departments (id and name), the id in this record is what department the location is is currently associated with and used to compare to the dropdown list to show the current value. I don't need any of this other information passed via the departmentOther object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and JSON provided, accessing values.departmentOther.id will cause an error because values is initialized as an empty object and departmentOther is not a property of that empty object.

You can update the fetchData function to the following:

> const fetchData = async () => {   const res = await
> axios.get(`${editUrl + (selectedRecord.id)}`);   setValues({
> ...res.data, departmentOther: res.data.departmentOther }); };